# richfaces progressBar polling

Tags: seam, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I've got a progressBar component defined as the following on my webpage:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="pb1Panel">
    <rich:progressBar id="pb1" oncomplete="javascript:#{myBean.handleProgressEvent()} closeProgressModalPanel()" value="#{pb1Listener.percentageComplete}" label="#{pb1Listener.percentageComplete} %" minValue="1" maxValue="100" limitToList="true" timeout="3200" interval="1400" enabled="false"/>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

and a button:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="actButton" value="action" action="#{myBean.performAction}" immediate="true" ajaxSingle="true" onclick="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('pb1Panel');" reRender="pb1Panel">
    <a4j:support event="onClick" value="#{rich:component('pb1')}.enable()" reRender="pb1" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

which doesn't work. However if I take out the

```
....
   enabled="false"/>
....
```

from the progress bar, and the  element from the button, everything seems to work just fine.

Any suggestion why it's not working? I'm setting enabled="false" initially because I do not want the polling to start unless the button was clicked (to reduce unnecessary polling).

The system is building on richfaces/seam.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enabled` property should refer to a property of a managed bean, and your button should change it, then reRender the progress bar.

Simply copy-paste the example from [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/progressBar.jsf?c=progressBar&tab=usage) - it's doing exactly the same thing as you want.